# C++ program to find and replace a string in file

Tags: c++

This is a beginner question. I am trying to find a string in text file and replace it back to the same file. Following code works fine collecting contents of file into buffer and replace the string . But when i try to keep the data back to same file, it is filled with some junk character. Please let me know what I am doing wrong ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

const char *fileName = "Test.dat";

int main () {

// This is where we'll put the stuff we read from file
char buffer[ 100 ];


ifstream finout(fileName, ios_base::in | ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);

if(!finout.is_open())
{
    cout << "Can not open file " << endl;
    return(1);
}

while (finout.getline(buffer, sizeof(buffer))
{
    string g( buffer );
    string search = "am";
    string replace = "was";
    long j;

    if ( (j = g.find(str2)) != string::npos)
    {    
        g.replace(g.find(str2), str2.length(), "str");
        finout.write((char *) &g, sizeof(g)); //This won't work 

    }

cout << g << "\n";
finout.close();
return 0;
}
```

My Test.dat file contain following information:

```
Hello, How are you?
I am fine.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When you are read/write as a text file, do not open it by `ios_base::binary`
- You put `finout.close();` inside your reading loop, so it just work for one line.
- When you are reading/writing a file as a text, use text stream methods and operators.

Comment: Thanks !! It worked. I wrote altered contents into a temporary file. And added following code to copy the temp file contents to original after while loop. finout << fout.rdbuf; if(!fout.eof()) std::cerr << "reading from file failed\n"; if(!finout.good()) std::cerr << "writing to file failed\n"; now fout points to temp file. But everytime it throws error that reading from a file is failed. Did i miss anything here ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read the size of your string with the `sizeof()` operator.

This wont work, because it is a keyword, that gives you the non-dynamic size of the object or type.

You should use `g.size()` to access the string size!

But on the first place, you can handle the stream handle your bug:

```
finout << g;
```

will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to both read and write a file, so use fstream not ifstream.
Second, you have a text file, so don't use ios_base::binary
Third (char*) &g where g is std::string doesn't work, use g.c_str() instead. (simply write
finout << g;

Now you can start thinking of the implmentation...